# How to use PM2 Cluster with Socket IO?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, pm2

I am developing an application that relies completely on Socket.io. As we all know NodeJS by default runs only on one core. Now I would like to scale it across multiple cores. I am finding it difficult to make socketio work with PM2 Cluster Mode. Any sample code would help.

I am using Artillery to test. And when the app runs on single core I get the response while It runs in cluster the response would be NaN

[image: When Ran in a Cluster]

[When Ran Without Cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USj88.png)

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

PM2 docs say

> Be sure your application is stateless meaning that no local data is
>   stored in the process, for example sessions/websocket connections,
>   session-memory and related. Use Redis, Mongo or other databases to
>   share states between processes.

Socket.io is not stateless.

Kubernetes implementation get around the statefull issues by routing based on source IP to a specific instance. This is still not 100% since some sources may present more than one IP address.  I know this is not PM2, but gives you an idea of the complexity.

Comment: stateless makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

**NESTjs SERVER**

I use Socket server 2.4.1 so then i get the compatible redis adapter that is 5.4.0

I need to extend nest's adepter class "ioAdapter" that class only works for normal ws connections not our pm2 clusters

```
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import * as redisIOAdapter from 'socket.io-redis';
import { config } from './config';

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  createIOServer(port: number, options?: any): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options);
    const redisAdapter = redisIOAdapter({
      host: config.server.redisUrl,
      port: config.server.redisPort,
    });
    server.adapter(redisAdapter);
    return server;
  }
}
```

That is actually nestjs implementation

Now i need to tell nest im using that implementetion so i go to main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { config } from './config';
import { RedisIoAdapter } from './socket-io.adapter';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

async function bootstrap() {
  EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisIoAdapter(app));
  await app.listen(config.server.port);
}
bootstrap();
```

I have a lot of events for this one so i had to up my max event count

now for every gateway you got, you need to use a different connection strategy, so instead of using polling you need to go to websocket directly

```
...
@WebSocketGateway({ transports: ['websocket'] })
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
...
```

or if you are using namespaces

```
...
@WebSocketGateway({ transports: ['websocket'], namespace: 'user' })
export class UsersGateway {
...
```

last step is to [install the redis database on your AWS instance and that is another thing;](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04) and also install pm2

```
nest build
pm2 i -g pm2
pm2 start dist/main.js -i 4
```

**CLIENT**

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = {
  url: environment.server.admin_url, //http:localhost:3000
  options: {
    transports: ['websocket'],
  },
};
```

You can now test your websocket server using [FireCamp](https://firecamp.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this lib:

https://github.com/luoyjx/socket.io-redis-stateless

It makes socket io stateless through redis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Redis with your Node server. Here is how I managed to get cluster mode to work with Socket.io

First install Redis. If you are using Ubuntu, follow this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04

Then:

```
npm i socket.io-redis
```

Now place Redis in your Node server

```
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis')

global.io = require('socket.io')(server, { transports: [ 'websocket' ]})

io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }))
```

That was all I had to do to get PM2 cluster mode to work with socket.io in my server.